# generate a class method “reject”, which is already defined by ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After the upgrade, I got the same error on each active record model using enum.

> ArgumentError (You tried to define an enum named “enum_key” on the model “Modal”, but this will generate a class method “reject”, which is already defined by ActiveRecord::Relation.

Please suggest the solution

Comment: After _what_ upgrade?

Comment: Please share the code that causes the exception, the full error message and the stack trace.